# Which jinni commands support paths containing ${config.base}?

Tags: hiconic

I have a yaml file configured to setup my local tomcat platform. I refer to the `jdbc.jar` via

```
${config.base}\res\jdbc.jar
```

I ran `jinni from-file my-setup.yaml` and the setup process couldn't finish due to error:

```
ERROR: java.nio.NoSuchFileException: ${config.base}\res\jdbc.jar
```

I tried to run the setup with jinni's alias logic via `jinni setup-main.yaml` and it worked.

Which commands do support context sensitive paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following ways of executing a command support placeholders:

- `jinni from-file <file> -v`
- `jinni <command-alias>`

In case of command `from-file` you have to use a yaml serialized file and you have to add option `-v` to activate placeholder resolution. The option is required due to backwards compatibility as there was no support for placeholders and therefore no awareness for escaping in earlier versions.

The `command-alias` way supports placeholders by default.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Both ways work for me now.